# How to Find how many Letters does a Text Box's value has in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office, vba7, vba6

I Wish there is a way to get the *amount of the characters of a Text Box Value* so I can limit it to be the amount that I wanted.
so like when someone entered *134131323* as the *Year of Date*, I can limit it to *4 characters*.

Also I the programming language is *VBA* and I do it in *[Microsoft Access](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/access)*.

I Did try to get it working with doing `txtTest.Value.Characters` idk but that did not work obviously and I DID SEARCH THE WHOLE INTERNET but I did not get A SINGLE RISULT. I Am a noob so someone help

Comment: `Len(txtTest.Value)` ?

Comment: For MS Access this post has a choice of answers ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55930690/how-to-limit-number-of-characters-of-form-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the *AfterUpdate* event of the textbox:

```vb
Private Sub YourTextbox_AfterUpdate()

    Const MaxLength As Integer = 4
    Dim Text        As String
    
    Text = Nz(Me!YourTextbox.Value)
    
    If Len(Text) > MaxLength Then
        Me!YourTextbox.Value = Left(Text, MaxLength)
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Len function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/len-function) available in VBA which returns a long containing the number of characters in a string or the number of bytes required to store a variable. For example:

```
Dim MyString, MyLen
MyString = "Hello World"    ' Initialize variable.

MyLen = Len(MyString)    ' Returns 11.
```